# If I use "compact" to compress a NTFS drive, how can I avoid compressing compressed files?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs

The following command compresses an entire NTFS drive:

```
compact e: /s /c /i
```

How do compress an entire drive, ignoring previously compressed files (in particular, .zip, .rar and .tib)?

Compressing a ".tib" file is pointless: its an Acronis TrueImage file, about 15GB, and as its already compressed it makes no savings to disk space, while wasting about 2 hours of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to either compress all files and then later uncompress the ones you do not want compressed, or put the files you don't want compressed in separate directories and then do not select those directories when you are choosing files/folders to be compressed.

Windows does not provide a facility for marking a file to "not be compressed."

Comment: Yes - I'm wondering if there is a 3rd party utility, much like Microsoft's "compact" that can offer selective compression of files on an entire hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that may be scripted.

- For each file in path, recursively traversing directories

  - If file name does not end up in .tib or .jpg or .avi or..

    - Then compress the file

You may try doing it in batch, or Powershell or Autohotkey.
Recursively traversing directories looks hard but I found this and you can do FOR /R in batch
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261517/batch-copy-script-recursive

Now you'd need to write a script (batch or other) that does "if (not ending in .tib AND not ending in .rar etc.) then compress"